# _CLLocationDistanceMax causes iOS 5.0 to crash, but no deprication found in class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-location

We had an app pushed to the appstore, which sadly seems to crash right on startup, but only on iOS 5.0, and only on distribution builds.

The error code presented in the crash logs are as follows :

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _CLLocationDistanceMax
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/761DB0F1-E766-4DA7-A335-7F0FC53CA72C/Carlsberg.app/Carlsberg
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/761DB0F1-E766-4DA7-A335-7F0FC53CA72C/Carlsberg.app/Carlsberg
  Dyld Version: 199.6
```

Removing the **CLLocationDistanceMax** from the app cures this crash, but there are no indications in the framework that iOS 5.0 can not handle this key.

I see no **__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING** variables or similar marking that this code is dangerous to use, and when building regular builds (debug builds) no crashes occur. Using adHoc distribution seems to have a somewhat "random" crash frequency.

I am using it like so :

```
CLRegion *nearby  = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:myloc.coordinate radius:CLLocationDistanceMax identifier:@"test"];;
```

Can it really be that Apple forgot to mark this object as 6.0+ only ?

Comment: Nick Bull is right, but how do you use CLLocationDistanceMax in you code? could you post some lines?

Comment: Im just confused there are no __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING on it. But yes, I've added the code im using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was only added in iOS6.

[iOS 6 Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/)

Answer (score 0):

It is ios6 only but not marked as such in the headers/documentation
http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=2845402